# When does "nature" require an article and why?

Tags: articles, names, proper-nouns, abstract-nouns, personification

I was wondering about a sentence like this:

1. If **nature** were to design a bicycle, how would it look?

Is *nature* missing an article? Should it be *a nature* or *the nature*, or is it correct as is?

2. If **a nature** were to design a bicycle, how would it look?
3. If **the nature** were to design a bicycle, how would it look?

Could you also explain why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Nature, in this context, means "Mother Nature", so it's more of a proper name in this case, which never requires an article.

'Nature' can also mean "a defining trait" as a general noun, such as "Human nature". In those casees, articles are possible, such as in

> it is the nature of the scorpion to sting

I can't think of an example where one would use "a nature", with an indefinite article, except in compound words such as

> He is a nature lover

in which case the article refers to the "lover" part, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are several of these words that spring to mind :)

Compare for instance

All earth's children are beautiful.
Earth's atmosphere protects it.
We only have one earth, we should cherish it.

Or, slightly in a different direction:

God's creation is beautiful.
Many a god lived on Olympus.
The god of small things.

When used without an article, we refer to the entity or idea as a personification of that idea or entity. With an article we refer to it as either a specific instantiation or physical representation of the idea.

Comment: "We only have one earth" does not work as an example. The article is absent because of the presence of *one*. It has nothing whatsoever to do with what noun follows.